# Group cohomology of sheaves under closed immersion

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, group-cohomology, sheaf-cohomology, galois-cohomology

Suppose $X$ is a scheme over Spec $\mathbb{Z}$, and $p$ is a non-zero prime in $\mathbb{Z}$. Then we have a closed immersion from the special fibre $i_p: X_p \rightarrow X$. If $\mathscr{F}$ is a sheaf of $\mathscr{O}_X[G]$-modules on $X$ for some finite group $G$ which is also considered to act on Spec $\mathbb{Z}$ trivially, I'd like to know the general relationship between the group cohomologies $H^i(G, \mathscr{F}_x)$ of stalks $\mathscr{F}_x$ with respect to $G$ and the group cohomologies $H^i(G, (i_p^*\mathscr{F})_{\bar{x}})$ of stalks $(i_p^* \mathscr{F})_{\bar{x}}$ on $X_p$ with respect to $G$ where $x = i(\bar{x})$, $x \in X$.

Is it simply given by group cohomologies induced from the short exact sequence of $\mathscr{O}_{X, x}[G]$-modules
$$0 \rightarrow p \cdot \mathscr{F}_x \rightarrow \mathscr{F}_x \rightarrow (i_{p*}i_p^* \mathscr{F})_x \rightarrow 0,$$
so, for example, we have a long exact sequence of group cohomologies of stalks given by
$$\cdots \rightarrow p \cdot H^i(G, \mathscr{F}_x) \rightarrow H^i(G, \mathscr{F}_x) \rightarrow H^i(G, (i_{p*} i_p^* \mathscr{F})_x) \rightarrow \cdots?$$
Does whether $p$ divides the order of $G$ or not play a role here?

I have studied algebraic geometry using Hartshorne's book up to chapter 2 and almost no background in Galois module theory, so I would deeply appreciate if someone could point out what I'm missing and guide me to references to learn more about this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is Galois module theory?

Comment: I didn't delve into the topic much due to limited time to comprehend but as I looked up R[G]-module structures of G-modules for a ring R, Galois module theory came up with its use of group cohomologies. Sorry I'm self-learning this topic and just have a vague impression that this is related to Galois module theory.

Comment: What do you mean by $H^i(X, \mathscr F, G)$?

Comment: I think I was confused with what I was asking with $H^i(X, \mathscr F, G)$, so I changed the question to ask for $H^i(G, \mathscr{F}_x)$. Since each stalk $\mathscr{F}_x$ is a $G$-module, its group cohomology now makes sense. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: It seems that the scheme and the sheaf are completely irrelevant, you just have some $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$-module $M$ with a $G$-action and want to relate $H^i(G, M)$ and $H^i(G, M/p)$. The exact sequence you wrote seems to be the way to go. Be careful with $p$-torsion though, since if $M$ has $p$-torsion then $pH^i(G, M) \neq H^i(G, pM)$.

Comment: Thank you @PiotrAchinger. Would you be able to suggest a reference to learn more about the last statement on when $M$ has a $p$-torsion element?

Comment: @OldStudentL I just meant that then $p\colon M\to pM$ is not injective, so the kernel of $M\to M/p$ can no longer be identified with $M$.